# Define mat-card-title width using percentage

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material2, md-card

I would center mat-card-title text. so I need to put it's width to 100% but I don't get a result, only if I use "px".

So I tried to put a width to all parents containers but no result .

Here's my html file

```
<div Fxlaout="row" fxLayoutGap="20px" class="container">
    <div fxFlex=30>
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>Collaborateurs sur ce projet</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>

                <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let per of Projet?.pers">
                    <mat-list-item role="listitem">Nom : {{per.name}}</mat-list-item>
                    <mat-list-item role="listitem">poste : {{per.poste}}</mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex>
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>Les fonctionnalités du produit</mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-content>
                <mat-list role="list" *ngFor="let func of Projet?.backlog.fonctionnalite; let i=index">
                   <mat-list-item role="listitem">Fonctionnalité #{{i}} : {{func.fonctionnalite}}</mat-list-item>
                </mat-list>
            </mat-card-content>
         </mat-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS file

```
  mat-card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  mat-card-header {
    background-color: #116a94;
    color: white;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .container {
    background-color: #87b6bd;
    width: 100%;
  }
  mat-card-title {
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
  }

  div {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I also added width persentage in my app.component.ts where I call my component:

```
<app-navabar></app-navabar>
<div style="width:100%">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

then I styles.css file I added `width:100%` to the body.

I don't see where is the element that does not having a width of x%

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Angular Material is wrapping your `<mat-card-title>` inside a `<div>` with a class `mat-card-header-text`. One way to overcome this is to override the class by adding the following to your css:

```
/deep/ .mat-card-header-text {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Tip - use Google Chrome Developer Tools to debug the compiled HTML next time you have a similar problem.
[image: Compiled HTML]

Comment: thanks that's working . I always use Chrome Dev Tool but I didn't paid attention to this

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to add:

```
  .mat-card-header-text {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .mat-card-header {
    justify-content: center;
  }
```